# iOS - UI Test check if video is played or not

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Hello I have an app that will open a webview that will open a page with video tag inside.
I want to write a UI test to confirm if the video is correctly played or not.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by "correctly played". What you could test is if a video is played when you press the play button. But you cannot really test if it is the right video.

Pressing the play button of a video that is embedded via video tag is a bit tricky. I can think of 2 approaches:

**1. Try to record the test.**

Depending on the structure of your HTML, the code created by Xcode can be quite ugly (Even worse: Sometimes Xcode cannot even record the pressing of the play button).

I recorded a UITest for a webview that loaded this URL: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

This is what I got:

```
func testVideo() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        app.children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other)["HTML5 Video"].children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 5).buttons["Start Playback"].tap()

        sleep(2)

        XCTAssert(app.buttons["Done"].exists)

    }
```

Yuck! Really ugly but it works. The tests starts the video and tests if the "Done" button exists, which is true when the videos plays. (I had to add the `sleep` statement to make the assertion work)

If recording the test does not work, there is another solution that you can use:

**2. Use a tap on a coordinate to start the video:**

```
func testVideo() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        sleep(2)

        app.windows.element(boundBy: 0).coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.8)).tap()

        sleep(2)

        XCTAssert(app.buttons["Done"].exists)
    }
```

Here you access the app's window and tap on a coordinate that is defined as 50% of the width and 80% of the height. (Have a look at the screenshot to see that that's the location of the button in my case). Of course you have to define you own coordinate that works in your case.

[image]

This solution works but it is really shaky. If the video's position on the page changes your test will break. Also the coordinate will change for different devices. And you have to experiment with the `sleep` statements to make it work. So it should probably only be used as a last resort.

**Testing if a video is actually being played:**

When the test starts the video the app goes into fullscreen mode and plays the video using the media player. To test that a video is actually being played you can access the position slider and check its `value`. The slider's value is a string (e.g. "12%), so to check if it is not still at 0% you have to convert it to a numeric value and assert that that value is greater than 0:

```
func testVideo() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        sleep(2)

        app.windows.element(boundBy: 0).coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.8)).tap()

        sleep(2)

        let currentPositionSlider = app.sliders.element(boundBy: 0)
        let percentageValueString = (currentPositionSlider.value as! String).replacingOccurrences(of: "%", with: "")
        let percentangeValue = Int(percentageValueString) ?? 0
        XCTAssert(percentangeValue > 0)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Actually I have no problem getting to the step to play the video, but after the video played it will go fullscreen and will be played on media player that will be out of application scope (I guess?) and I can't confirm anything from there. Any idea how to confirm if the media player slide bar has correct value not always 00:00?

Comment: You can access the media player current position slider and check that its value is greater than 0. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: That's great! Will check that one and inform you later about it! Thanks a lot man!